# Using IAX2 to call from one Asterisk server to another

Tags: asterisk

I have two asterisk servers serverA and serverB . I am trying to place a call from serverA to use serverB using IAX2. I have defined a user on serverB in iax.conf. When making the call this is what I see on serverA:

```
Attempting call on IAX2/iax_user:password@serverBip/xyzno for s@custom-try-play:1 (Retry 1)
Max retries exceeded to host serverBip on IAX2/serverBip:4569-8181 (type = 6, subclass = 1, ts=19, seqno=0)
Hungup 'IAX2/serverBip:4569-8181
```

There is no output on serverB when I use the CLI with verbosity 5. I have checked that the UDP port 4569 is open on serverB. How can I check why the call is failing?

Comment: Have you performed a packet capture on B to verify the packets are actually making it there?

Comment: This is standart inter-asterisk exchange scenario. Have you checked books? Also it is bad idea use callfiles/ami originate to test interconnect. Test with softphones first.

Comment: Can you post the relevant chunks of iax.conf?